# Puntuación de comentarios del narrador antes del diálogo

Tags: gramática, puntuación

Tengo este diálogo y no estoy segura de la puntuación:

> Juan se asoma a la habitación y le sonríe a Ana.— ¡Traigo novedades! —anuncia.
>
> Ana le mira.— ¿Qué novedades?

¿Es correcto esto? ¿O las intervenciones previas del narrador deben ir en un párrafo separado, así?

> Juan se asoma a la habitación y le sonríe a Ana.
>
> — ¡Traigo novedades! —anuncia.
>
> Ana le mira.
>
> — ¿Qué novedades?

¿Y qué pasaría si en lugar de `"Ana le mira"` fuera `"Ana pregunta"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo usual es que cada parlamento tenga su propio párrafo. No se pone espacio después de la raya. El párrafo anterior puede terminar en dos puntos.

> Juan se asoma a la habitación y le sonríe a Ana.
>
> —¡Traigo novedades! —anuncia.
>
> Ana pregunta:
>
> —¿Qué novedades?
>
> —Éstas.

Raras veces un escritor o traductor puede decidir no hacer esto, y poner un parlamento en medio de un párrafo. Generalmente cuando se traduce del inglés, para no perder el ritmo. (Esto recuerdo que lo vi en la traducción de *El Señor de los Anillos*.)

En ese caso, simplemente se deja un espacio antes de cada raya.

> Juan se asoma a la habitación y le sonríe a Ana. —¡Traigo novedades! —anuncia. Ana pregunta: —¿Qué novedades? —Éstas.

Pero no es para nada recomendable.

Comment: Gracias! Efectivamente, estoy mucho más acostumbrada a escribir diálogo en inglés, que es más permisivo creo con la combinación de parlamentos y narración.